# How to extend JavaFX Line or other shapes

Tags: java, javafx, line

I want to extend the JavaFX class Line, cause i want the startpoint and endingpoint to be a circle or arrow or sth. like that. In addition to that, i want to tag the line in the future.
The problem is how to overwrite the paint method? What method is responsible for drawing the line and how do I have to implement my wishes?
Until now, i got that, but if I instaciate a Line it doesn´t change the appearance:

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class LabeledLine extends Line {
    private Circle startCircle;
    private Circle endCircle;

    public LabeledLine(){
        super();
        startCircle = new Circle(getStartX(), getStartY(), 10);
        endCircle = new Circle(getEndX(), getEndY(), 10);
        startCircle.setFill(getFill());
        endCircle.setFill(getFill());
    }


    public LabeledLine(double startX, double startY, double endX, double endY){
        super(startX, startY, endX, endY);
        startCircle = new Circle(getStartX(), getStartY(), 10);
        endCircle = new Circle(getEndX(), getEndY(), 10);
        startCircle.setFill(getFill());
        endCircle.setFill(getFill());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the implementation you provided won't work if, e.g. you were to do

```
LabeledLine l = new LabeledLine() ;
l.setStartX(100);
```

It is actually quite difficult to fix this using a strategy of subclassing `Line`.

At any rate, `Shape`s are rendered by delegating to a private native peer class, which (as I understand it) allows them to be rendered highly efficiently by a hardware graphics pipeline in many cases. So there is no accessible "paint" method for you to override here.

Instead, subclass `Group` and let your subclass wrap a line (basically, this is "favor composition over inheritance" from *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch):

```
public class LabeledLine extends Group {

    public LabeledLine(Line line) {
        Circle startCircle = new Circle(10);
        startCircle.centerXProperty().bind(line.startXProperty());
        startCircle.centerYProperty().bind(line.startYProperty());
        startCircle.fillProperty().bind(line.fillProperty());
        Circle endCircle = new Circle(10);
        endCircle.centerXProperty().bind(line.endXProperty());
        endCircle.centerYProperty().bind(line.endYProperty());
        endCircle.fillProperty().bind(line.fillProperty());

        getChildren().addAll(line, startCircle, endCircle);
    }
}
```

You would then use this as:

```
Line line = new Line();
Pane somePane = new Pane();
somePane.getChildren().add(new LabeledLine(line));
```

---

Note also that the implementation above actually adds no state or behavior to `Group`, so you could completely refactor it as a method:

```
public Group labelLine(Line line) {
    Circle startCircle = new Circle(10);
    startCircle.centerXProperty().bind(line.startXProperty());
    startCircle.centerYProperty().bind(line.startYProperty());
    startCircle.fillProperty().bind(line.fillProperty());
    Circle endCircle = new Circle(10);
    endCircle.centerXProperty().bind(line.endXProperty());
    endCircle.centerYProperty().bind(line.endYProperty());
    endCircle.fillProperty().bind(line.fillProperty());

    return new Group(line, startCircle, endCircle);
}
```

and then

```
Pane somePane = new Pane();
Line line = new Line();
somePane.getChildren().add(labelLine(line));
```

Comment: Did you try your implementation? They look pretty well, but i wonder why they don't work. If i run this, all I see is just a normal line...

Comment: Late response, but the issue is with `startCircle.fillProperty().bind(line.fillProperty());` and the corresponding binding for the endCircle. FillProperty is Null for lines, so that makes the circles invisible. If you set an explicit fillProperty, bind the fillProperty to the line's strokeProperty, or set the line's fillProperty, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent of my knowledge you shouldn't extend base Shapes directly. Rather extend `Region` and use a composed `Line` as a child node.

https://github.com/aalmiray/jsilhouette uses a similar approach. Properties are set on types that "look like" Shapes but aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this here, and it worked well:

```
public Group labelLine(Line line) {
    Circle startCircle = new Circle(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), 10);
    Circle endCircle = new Circle(line.getEndX(), line.getEndY(), 10);

    return new Group(line, startCircle, endCircle);
}
```

Still wonderin why your implementation won't work, because it looks nice.

Comment: See my comment above. The issue is binding to the line's fill property, which is null by default. Set the line's fill property or bind to something like the stroke property and it works fine.